# Is it safe to ignore O_DIRECT?

Tags: filesystems, posix, fuse

I am going to implement a filesystem in FUSE, and later in the kernel. I am not sure what to make out of Direct IO. Different sources emphasize on different things that this flag supposedly implies.

**Is it safe for a filesystem to just ignore O_DIRECT?**

- Read and write operations would proceed like normal. Open would ignore it and not fail.
- Data checksums would still be be verified. Therefore a read operation may fail due to checksum even if hard disk returned OK.
- Written data would be subject to copy on write and delayed allocation.
- Write operations would return OK immediately. Writeback would happen after a delay, or never in case of power out. Durability is not guaranteed, but this is O_SYNC sementic anyway.

Few issues come to mind.

- Caching file content in the Buffer/Page cache is, to my understanding, a responsibility of the VFS and not the filesystem. Does VFS also interpret this flag?
- [According to one answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/use-of-o-direct-on-linux), flag may fail on future kernels. Comment under the answer explains that Direct IO is contrary to data journaling mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the `open(2)` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html):

```
   O_DIRECT (since Linux 2.4.10)
          Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this
          file.  In general this will degrade performance, but it is
          useful in special situations, such as when applications do
          their own caching.  File I/O is done directly to/from user-
          space buffers.  The O_DIRECT flag on its own makes an effort
          to transfer data synchronously, but does not give the
          guarantees of the O_SYNC flag that data and necessary metadata
          are transferred.  To guarantee synchronous I/O, O_SYNC must be
          used in addition to O_DIRECT.  See NOTES below for further
          discussion.
```

From the NOTES section:

```
   O_DIRECT support was added under Linux in kernel version 2.4.10.
   Older Linux kernels simply ignore this flag.  Some filesystems may
   not implement the flag and open() will fail with EINVAL if it is
   used.
```

So O_DIRECT used to be simply ignored.  And [from the LKML](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/8/25/396), just a couple of months ago:

> > Who cares how a filesystem implements O_DIRECT as long as it does
> >     not corrupt data? ext3 fell back to buffered IO in many situations,
> >     yet the only complaints about that were performance. IOWs, it's long been
> >     true that if the user cares about O_DIRECT *performance* then they
> >     have to be careful about their choice of filesystem.
> >
> > But if it's only 5 lines of code per filesystem to support O_DIRECT
> >     *correctly* via buffered IO, then exactly why should userspace have
> >     to jump through hoops to explicitly handle open(O_DIRECT) failure?
> >
> > Especially when you consider that all they can do is fall back to
> >     buffered IO themselves....
>
> I had written counterpoints for all of this, but I thought better of
>   it.  Old versions of the kernel simply ignore O_DIRECT, so clearly
>   there's precedent.

Given that, it seems that you're safe to simply ignore it.  The key phrase seems to be to "not corrupt data".

For now.

Note also that your [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/use-of-o-direct-on-linux) has answers that say O_DIRECT isn't useful for performance reasons.  That is simply incorrect.  Passing data through the page cache is slower than *not* passing it through the page cache.  That can be significant on hardware capable of transferring gigabytes per second.  And if you only handle each bit of data one time, the caching is literally useless yet it will needlessly impact the entire system.

It's been a few years since I wrote a Linux filesystem module.  Unfortunately I don't recall how the VFS systems handle caching.